# BEP-20 Token Transaction on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, binance, binance-smart-chain

Hi I'm just confused that how to transact BEP-20 Token(e.g: Binance-Peg BUSD-T). I have simply transact bnb in Binance Smart Chain with this code:

```
const tx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
  to: '0xB1455f4721b32390f4b65F86D2Cd50e74FaD7A99',
  value: '500000000000000',
  gas: 2000000
}, 'SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY');
  
const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx.rawTransaction);
```

And it work perfectly fine. But I just do absolutely anything to transact a token, for example I used web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_addr) and then

```
await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, '500000000000000000').send({ 
  from: '0xF9FF794700224fc9a1D6a30eb2A90d11eA1D82D1'
});
```

or with ethereumjs-tx package and ..., but none of them transact the token. I just need a sample code example or a well documented blog to tell me what should I do. Can anyone help me with that ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `.send({from: ...})` method, you need to

- Have the `from` account unlocked on your provider.

  OR
- Add its private key to the web3 account wallet ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add))

---

**Ulocked provider account**

This approach is mostly used on local providers (e.g. Ganache) that fund and unlock some accounts by default.

Keeping an unlocked account on a production provider is unwise, because anyone who queries the provider can send transactions.

---

**Web3 account wallet**

You need to pass the private key that generates the `from` address.

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKey);
```

And then you can use the `.send({from: ...})` method

```
await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, '500000000000000000').send({ 
  from: '0xF9FF794700224fc9a1D6a30eb2A90d11eA1D82D1'
});
```

Comment: OHHHHHHH !!! thanks man. You saved my hole month for this. But there is still a tiny issue. I was able to do the transaction and the amount was transferred. But the code will throw this error. `insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0xF9FF794700224fc9a1D6a30eb2A90511eA1D82D1 have 91521965000000000 want 500000000000000000 (supplied gas 25000000)`. Do you know how to find out the gas ???

Comment: The round number `500000000000000000` suggests that the called function throws an exception that would consume all available gas. So you should debug your function first and find out whether and why it's throwing the exception (e.g. a failed `require()` or `assert()` statement) ... For estimating gas required to execute a function, you can use the [estimateGas()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) method.

Comment: Alright. As you said that was a mistake of gasPrice when defining `web3.eth.Contract`. I just make it `200000000` and I think it will work all the time. Again, thanks a lot ...

Comment: And what is your suggestion for solving `transaction underpriced`. I read that I should increase gasPrice by 10%. I just don't know what to do because I make so many transactions.

Comment: Please how do I get the sender private key ?